# How to verify with StepVerifier that provided Mono did not completed?

Tags: project-reactor

With `StepVerifier` it is very easy to check whether provided `Mono` has completed (just by `expectComplete()` method in `StepVerifier`), but what should I do if need to check the opposite case ?

I tried to use this approach:

```
    @Test
    public void neverMonoTest() {
        Mono<String> neverMono = Mono.never();
        StepVerifier.create(neverMono)
            .expectSubscription()
            .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .thenCancel()
            .verify();
    }
```

and such test passes. But this is false positive, because when I replace `Mono.never()` with `Mono.empty()` the test is still green.

Is there any better and reliable method to check lack of Mono's completion (of course within given scope of time) ?

Comment: I think this *should* work, and you're probably hitting this bug (https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1913). You could try downgrading your `reactor-test` dependency to `3.1.2` and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: @MichaelBerry, thanks for explanation. Downgrade to 3.1.2 indeed fixed the problem.

Comment: No problem. I'll go ahead and turn that into an answer, since I don't think there's a "better" thing to do at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're hitting a [bug in reactor-test](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1913), and unfortunately one that doesn't look to be solved any time soon:

> Due to my memory that was a constant flaw in design of reactor-test. Most likely that will be fixed once reactor-test will be rewritten from scratch / significantly.

Downgrading to 3.1.2 seems to fix the problem, but that's quite a downgrade. The only other workaround I'm aware of was [posted by PyvesB here](https://github.com/reactor/lite-rx-api-hands-on/issues/52#issuecomment-545378776), and involves waiting for the Mono to timeout:

```
Mono<String> mono = Mono.never();
StepVerifier.create(mono.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1L)))
        .verifyError(TimeoutException.class);
```

When the next release rolls out, then [you should be able to do](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/pull/1931):

```
Mono<String> mono = Mono.never();
StepVerifier.create(mono)
        .expectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
```

...as a more concise alternative.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, the workaround really is not so bad as it initially seems.

Comment: that makes me wonder if we could add another terminating expectation like `expectTimeoutAfter(Duration).verify()`/`verifyTimeoutAfter(Duration)`, which would replace `.expectNoEvent().thenCancel().verify()`... The noEvent bug fix is proving surprisingly elusive :(

Comment: @SimonBaslé I'm not surprised - I had a poke around in the code as best I could and quickly realised there wasn't any obvious (to me) "quick fix"! I'd be all for that expectation, especially since I suspect (maybe incorrectly) that's one of the most common use cases of `expectNoEvent()` anyway.